# How to get IR image from Kinect

Tags: ros, ir, images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need to get IR images from the kinect in c++. Does anyone know how to do it not using OpenCV? If not, is it complicated to add this library to my project which is one of the implemented projects in Kinect for windows developer toolkit v1.5.2?

Thanks,
Maniar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44538/how-to-get-ir-image-from-kinect/) by [Maniar](https://answers.ros.org/users/3253/maniar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS you can get it from the driver: http://ros.org/wiki/openni_camera. Just run roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch in one terminal and rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/ir/image_raw in the other. If you need just that bit of a code you will have to look into the driver implementation available in openni_camera package.

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2012-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3